# ssis csv space formatting issue

Tags: ssis

I am doing an ssis job which reads a csv file and loads into database after performing some logic .
The Problem is my job does not understand spaces in csv file . if I remove all the extra spaces between column values , it works fine but if it has space between the column value and comma , it fails .

FYI - The server where job is deployed does not have excel sp it opens up the file in wordpad and I remove all the extra spaces , it works fine . Please help

Comment: when you say it fails what is the error?  I am guessing a datatype error of some kind?  If so you could bring everythign in as string and then use derived columns to trim and change data type

Comment: Can you paste the error that you are facing?

Comment: Modelcode , description code, number,date,pol, pod X152 Jaguar (XK),  W5 , W5MCE , SALCA2BGXGH551590 ,  2015-08-28 ,  ,GBSOU, MXVER - if this is the data in csv file ,but if I format it with no extra spaces X152 Jaguar (XK),W5,W5MCE,SALCA2BGXGH551590,2015-08-28, ,GBSOU,MXVER  , it works fine .

Comment: the error I get is  it throws an error [OLE DB Destination [143]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".

Comment: [OLE DB Destination [143]] Error: There was an error with input column "Copy of Column 4" (238) on input "OLE DB Destination Input" (156). The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.". column 4 has space as value . I have checked its datatype . it all looks good